# Which assert to use to verify a text field

Tags: java, api, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

I want to assert a number appearing in a text field.
The id of the text field is blNo.
I am not able to use a proper assert.
Can anyone suggest me which assert I should use & also which pre-poulated template to select after the assert word.
Looking forward to some suggestions.

Comment: I would suggest an `assertTrue` with an regexp

Answer (score 0):

`assertEquals()` is overridden for most of the data types. For Integer you can use:

```
String inputValue = driver.findElement(By.id("blNo")).getText();
Assert.assertEquals(Integer.parseInt(inputValue), yournumber);
```

Here we need to `parseInt` since `getText()` always returns String.

Answer (score 0):

1. Get the value of text field and store it in string

   `string value = driver.FindElement(By.Id("blNo")).Text;`
   In java - use GetText() method to read the text and in C# 'Text' will solve the motive.
2. Convert the string value in Integer as you said you want to assert numbers

   int actual_number = int.Parse(value);
3. now Use `Assert.AreEqual(Expected-Value, Actual-Value);`